# Annoying sound when I connect my bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

Whenever I connect my USB dongle near the port where my headphone is plugged, I hear some disturbing , annoying sound from my headset. Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like there is some interference on you headphone lead being caused by the Bluetooth dongle.

The magnetic field and/or radio waves being emitted by the Bluetooth device are causing a secondary current to be induced in the lead of your headphones. This will be greatest when the dongle is plugged in or removed as the change (from off to on & vice versa) will be greatest during this time. This is a a natural phenomenon that you can't do anything about.

The solution is to either move the Bluetooth dongle to a USB port further away from the headphone socket or just leave it plugged in (assuming that the interference only happens when it's inserted into the socket).

Answer (score 1):

That is most likely because of RF interference. It's caused by combination of small distance between bluetooth dongle and jack and bad shielding in cable or soundcard or both. The easiest solution would be to move the dongle or to try with different dongle or headset. Still, there's no guarantee that those steps will actually help in your particular case.